# count repeated value ruby hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

My input data:

```
[
  {"discount_code"=>"LAKR", "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh"},
  {"discount_code"=>"LAKR", "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh"}, 
  {"discount_code"=>"LAKR", "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh"}, 
  {"discount_code"=>"LAKR", "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh"},  
  {"discount_code"=>"LAKR", "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh"}, 
  {"discount_code"=>"LAKR", "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh"}, 
  {"discount_code"=>"4567", "affiliate_name"=>"an"}, 
  {"discount_code"=>"LAKR", "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh"}
]
```

I want to transform it to this:

```
[
  {"discount_code"=>"LAKR", "count"=>7, "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh"},
  {"discount_code"=>"4567", "count"=>1, "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh"}
]
```

This has the input data with the count of the number of times it appeared, and no repeat values.

Answer (score 6):

If `arr` is your array:

```
arr.group_by(&:itself).map { |h,v| h.merge("count"=>v.size) }
  #=> [{"discount_code"=>"LAKR", "count"=>7, "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh"},
  #    {"discount_code"=>"4567", "count"=>1, "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh"}]
```

The steps:

```
h = arr.group_by(&:itself)
  #=> {{"discount_code"=>"LAKR", "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh"}=>
  #      [{"discount_code"=>"LAKR", "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh"},
  #       {"discount_code"=>"LAKR", "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh"},
  #       {"discount_code"=>"LAKR", "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh"},
  #       {"discount_code"=>"LAKR", "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh"},
  #       {"discount_code"=>"LAKR", "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh"},
  #       {"discount_code"=>"LAKR", "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh"},
  #       {"discount_code"=>"LAKR", "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh"}],
  #    {"discount_code"=>"4567", "affiliate_name"=>"an"}=>
  #      [{"discount_code"=>"4567", "affiliate_name"=>"an"}]}
enum = h.map
  #=> #<Enumerator: {
  #    {"discount_code"=>"LAKR", "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh"}=>
  #      [{"discount_code"=>"LAKR", "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh"},
  #       ...
  #       {"discount_code"=>"LAKR", "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh"}],
  #    {"discount_code"=>"4567", "affiliate_name"=>"an"}=>
  #      [{"discount_code"=>"4567", "affiliate_name"=>"an"}]}:map>
enum.each { |h,v| h.merge("count"=>v.size) }
  #=> [{"discount_code"=>"LAKR", "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh", "count"=>7},
  #    {"discount_code"=>"4567", "affiliate_name"=>"an", "count"=>1}]
```

The first element of `enum` is passed to the block and assigned to the block variables:

```
h,v = enum.next
  #=> [{"discount_code"=>"LAKR", "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh"},
  #    ...
  #    {"discount_code"=>"LAKR", "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh"}]]

h #=> {"discount_code"=>"LAKR", "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh"} 
v #=> [{"discount_code"=>"LAKR", "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh"},
  #    ...
  #    {"discount_code"=>"LAKR", "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh"}]
```

and the block calculation is performed:

```
h.merge("count"=>v.size)
  #=> h.merge("count"=>7)
  #=> {"discount_code"=>"LAKR", "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh", "count"=>7}
```

The remaining calculations are similar.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.uniq.map{|i| i.merge({'count' => arr.count(i)})}

=> [{"discount_code"=>"LAKR", "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh", "count"=>7}
{"discount_code"=>"4567", "affiliate_name"=>"an", "count"=>1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e, m| m[e] += 1 }.map { |k, v| k.merge("count" => v) }
# => [{"discount_code"=>"LAKR", "affiliate_name"=>"Jasbir Singh", "count"=>7}, {"discount_code"=>"4567", "affiliate_name"=>"an", "count"=>1}]
```